# Calculate date difference in year, month, day

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, aggregation-framework

I have the following query:

```
db.getCollection('user').aggregate([
   {$unwind: "$education"},
   {$project: {
      duration: {"$divide":[{$subtract: ['$education.to', '$education.from'] }, 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 365]}
   }},
   {$group: {
     _id: '$_id',
     "duration": {$sum: '$duration'}  
   }}]
])
```

Above query result is:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59fabb20d7905ef056f55ac1"),
    "duration" : 2.34794520547945
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59fab630203f02f035301fc3"),
    "duration" : 2.51232876712329
}
```

But what I want to do is get its duration in `year`+ `month` + `day` format, something like: `2 y, 3 m, 20 d`.
One another point, if a course is going on the `to` field is null, and another field `isGoingOn: true`, so here I should calculate the duration by using current date instead of `to` field.
And user has array of course subdocuments

```
education: [
   {
      "courseName": "Java",
      "from" : ISODate("2010-12-08T00:00:00.000Z"),
      "to" : ISODate("2011-05-31T00:00:00.000Z"), 
      "isGoingOn": false
   },
   {
      "courseName": "PHP",
      "from" : ISODate("2013-12-08T00:00:00.000Z"),
      "to" : ISODate("2015-05-31T00:00:00.000Z"), 
      "isGoingOn": false
   },
   {
      "courseName": "Mysql",
      "from" : ISODate("2017-02-08T00:00:00.000Z"),
      "to" : null, 
      "isGoingOn": true
   }
]
```

One another point is this: that date may be not continuous in one subdocument to the other subdocument. A user may have a course for 1 year, and then after two years, he/she started his/her next course for 1 year, and 3 months (it means this user has a total of 2 years and 3-month course duration).
What I want is get date difference of each subdocument in educations array, and sum those. Suppose in my sample data `Java` course duration is 6 month, and 22 days, `PHP` course duration is 1 year, and 6 months, and 22 days, and the last one is from 8 Feb 2017 till now, and it's going on, so my education duration is the sum of these intervals.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please try this aggregation to get date difference in days,months and years, added multiple `$addFields` stage compute and reduce differences to date, month range without underflow, and the assumption here is 1 month = 30 days

pipeline

```
db.edu.aggregate(
    [
        {
            $addFields : {
                trainingPeriod : {
                    $map : {
                        input : "$education",
                        as : "t",
                        in : {
                            year: {$subtract: [{$year : {$ifNull : ["$$t.to", new Date()]}}, {$year : "$$t.from"}]},
                            month: {$subtract: [{$month : {$ifNull : ["$$t.to", new Date()]}}, {$month : "$$t.from"}]},
                            dayOfMonth: {$subtract: [{$dayOfMonth : {$ifNull : ["$$t.to", new Date()]}}, {$dayOfMonth : "$$t.from"}]}
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        {
            $addFields : {
                trainingPeriod : {
                    $map : {
                        input : "$trainingPeriod",
                        as : "d",
                        in : {
                            year: "$$d.year",
                            month: {$cond : [{$lt : ["$$d.dayOfMonth", 0]}, {$subtract : ["$$d.month", 1]}, "$$d.month" ]},
                            day: {$cond : [{$lt : ["$$d.dayOfMonth", 0]}, {$add : [30, "$$d.dayOfMonth"]}, "$$d.dayOfMonth" ]}
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        {
            $addFields : {
                trainingPeriod : {
                    $map : {
                        input : "$trainingPeriod",
                        as : "d",
                        in : {
                            year: {$cond : [{$lt : ["$$d.month", 0]}, {$subtract : ["$$d.year", 1]}, "$$d.year" ]},
                            month: {$cond : [{$lt : ["$$d.month", 0]}, {$add : [12, "$$d.month"]}, "$$d.month" ]},
                            day: "$$d.day"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        {
            $addFields : {
                total : {
                    $reduce : {
                        input : "$trainingPeriod",
                        initialValue : {year : 0, month : 0, day : 0},
                        in : {
                            year: {$add : ["$$this.year", "$$value.year"]},
                            month: {$add : ["$$this.month", "$$value.month"]},
                            day: {$add : ["$$this.day", "$$value.day"]}
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        {
            $addFields : {
                total : {
                    year : "$total.year",
                    month : {$add : ["$total.month", {$floor : {$divide : ["$total.day", 30]}}]},
                    day : {$mod : ["$total.day", 30]}
                }
            }
        },
        {
            $addFields : {
                total : {
                    year : {$add : ["$total.year", {$floor : {$divide : ["$total.month", 12]}}]},
                    month : {$mod : ["$total.month", 12]},
                    day : "$total.day"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
).pretty()
```

result

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a895d4721cbd77dfe857f95"),
    "education" : [
        {
            "courseName" : "Java",
            "from" : ISODate("2010-12-08T00:00:00Z"),
            "to" : ISODate("2011-05-31T00:00:00Z"),
            "isGoingOn" : false
        },
        {
            "courseName" : "PHP",
            "from" : ISODate("2013-12-08T00:00:00Z"),
            "to" : ISODate("2015-05-31T00:00:00Z"),
            "isGoingOn" : false
        },
        {
            "courseName" : "Mysql",
            "from" : ISODate("2017-02-08T00:00:00Z"),
            "to" : null,
            "isGoingOn" : true
        }
    ],
    "trainingPeriod" : [
        {
            "year" : 0,
            "month" : 5,
            "day" : 23
        },
        {
            "year" : 1,
            "month" : 5,
            "day" : 23
        },
        {
            "year" : 1,
            "month" : 0,
            "day" : 10
        }
    ],
    "total" : {
        "year" : 2,
        "month" : 11,
        "day" : 26
    }
}
>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you could just simply use the existing [date aggregation operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation-date/)s as opposed to using math to convert to "days" as you presently have:

```
db.getCollection('user').aggregate([
  { "$unwind": "$education" },
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$_id",
    "years": {
      "$sum": {
        "$subtract": [
          { "$subtract": [
            { "$year": { "$ifNull": [ "$education.to", new Date() ] } },
            { "$year": "$education.from" }
          ]},
          { "$cond": {
            "if": {
              "$gt": [
                { "$month": { "$ifNull": [ "$education.to", new Date() ] } },
                { "$month": "$education.from" }
              ]
            },
            "then": 0,
            "else": 1
          }}
        ]
      }
    },
    "months": {
      "$sum": {
        "$add": [
          { "$subtract": [
            { "$month": { "$ifNull": [ "$education.to", new Date() ] } },
            { "$month": "$education.from" }
          ]},
          { "$cond": {
            "if": {
              "$gt": [
                { "$month": { "$ifNull": ["$education.to", new Date() ] } },
                { "$month": "$education.from" }
              ]
            },
            "then": 0,
            "else": 12
          }}
        ]
      }
    },
    "days": {
      "$sum": {
        "$add": [
          { "$subtract": [
            { "$dayOfYear": { "$ifNull": [ "$education.to", new Date() ] } },
            { "$dayOfYear": "$education.from" }
          ]},
          { "$cond": {
            "if": {
              "$gt": [
                { "$month": { "$ifNull": [ "$education.to", new Date() ] } },
                { "$month": "$education.from" }
              ]
            },
            "then": 0,
            "else": 365
          }}
        ]
      }
    }
  }},
  { "$project": {
    "years": {
      "$add": [
        "$years",
        { "$add": [
          { "$floor": { "$divide": [ "$months", 12 ] } },
          { "$floor": { "$divide": [ "$days", 365 ] } }
        ]}
      ]
    },
    "months": {
      "$mod": [
        { "$add": [
          "$months",
          { "$floor": {
            "$multiply": [
              { "$divide": [ "$days", 365 ] },
              12
            ]
          }}
        ]},
        12
      ]
    },
    "days": { "$mod": [ "$days", 365 ] }
  }}
])
```

It is "sort of" an approximation on the "days" and "months" without the necessary operations to be "certain" of leap years, but it would get you the result which should be "near enough" for most purposes.

You can even do this without [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) as long as your MongoDB version is 3.2 or greater:

```
db.getCollection('user').aggregate([
  { "$addFields": {
    "duration": {
      "$let": {
        "vars": {
          "edu": {
            "$map": {
              "input": "$education",
              "as": "e",
              "in": {
                "$let": {
                  "vars": { "toDate": { "$ifNull": ["$$e.to", new Date()] } },
                  "in": {
                    "years": {
                      "$subtract": [
                        { "$subtract": [
                          { "$year": "$$toDate" },
                          { "$year": "$$e.from" }   
                        ]},
                        { "$cond": {
                          "if": { "$gt": [{ "$month": "$$toDate" },{ "$month": "$$e.from" }] },
                          "then": 0,
                          "else": 1
                        }}
                      ]
                    },
                    "months": {
                      "$add": [
                        { "$subtract": [
                          { "$ifNull": [{ "$month": "$$toDate" }, new Date() ] },
                          { "$month": "$$e.from" }
                        ]},
                        { "$cond": {
                          "if": { "$gt": [{ "$month": "$$toDate" },{ "$month": "$$e.from" }] },
                          "then": 0,
                          "else": 12
                        }}
                      ]
                    },
                    "days": {
                      "$add": [
                        { "$subtract": [
                          { "$ifNull": [{ "$dayOfYear": "$$toDate" }, new Date() ] },
                          { "$dayOfYear": "$$e.from" }
                        ]},
                        { "$cond": {
                          "if": { "$gt": [{ "$month": "$$toDate" },{ "$month": "$$e.from" }] },
                          "then": 0,
                          "else": 365
                        }}
                      ]
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }    
          }
        },
        "in": {
          "$let": {
            "vars": {
              "years": { "$sum": "$$edu.years" },
              "months": { "$sum": "$$edu.months" },
              "days": { "$sum": "$$edu.days" }    
            },
            "in": {
              "years": {
                "$add": [
                  "$$years",
                  { "$add": [
                    { "$floor": { "$divide": [ "$$months", 12 ] } },
                    { "$floor": { "$divide": [ "$$days", 365 ] } }
                  ]}
                ]
              },
              "months": {
                "$mod": [
                  { "$add": [
                    "$$months",
                    { "$floor": {
                      "$multiply": [
                        { "$divide": [ "$$days", 365 ] },
                        12
                      ]
                    }}
                  ]},
                  12
                ]
              },
              "days": { "$mod": [ "$$days", 365 ] }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

This is because from MongoDB 3.4 you can use [`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) directly with an array of or any list of expressions in stages like [`$addFields`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/) or [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/), and the [`$map`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/map/) can apply those same "date aggregation operator" expressions against each array element in place of doing [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) first.

So the main math can really be done in one part of "reducing" the array, and then each total can be adjusted by the general "divisors" for the years, and the "modulo" or "remainder" from any overruns in the months and days.

Essentially returns:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a07688e98e4471d8aa87940"),
    "education" : [ 
        {
            "courseName" : "Java",
            "from" : ISODate("2010-12-08T00:00:00.000Z"),
            "to" : ISODate("2011-05-31T00:00:00.000Z"),
            "isGoingOn" : false
        }, 
        {
            "courseName" : "PHP",
            "from" : ISODate("2013-12-08T00:00:00.000Z"),
            "to" : ISODate("2015-05-31T00:00:00.000Z"),
            "isGoingOn" : false
        }, 
        {
            "courseName" : "Mysql",
            "from" : ISODate("2017-02-08T00:00:00.000Z"),
            "to" : null,
            "isGoingOn" : true
        }
    ],
    "duration" : {
        "years" : 3.0,
        "months" : 3.0,
        "days" : 259.0
    }
}
```

Given the 11th of November 2017

Comment: Your query calculate `year, month, day` separately, what i want is like `1 year and 2 month and 10 day`, not like `1 year, 14 month, 396 day`

Comment: @jones That's not going to happen. You can use the values produced to form a "string", but that's simply concatenating the values into a whole string, and that's really something that makes more sense to do in client code. You really should let the database "reduce" content naturally. Just as is shown here. And pay attention to what I actually did, as I **do** in fact adjust all of years, months and days accordingly.

Comment: @jones Think I misread your comment. Look again, I am indeed adjusting each part. It's just that the math here works differently to how you presume. I never get to 14 months. It's either positive or negative and then adjusted accordingly. Same with the years, based on the month.

Comment: I think my comment was not clear enough, Suppose duration of a course that user joined is `1 year and 2 month and 10 days`, i would like to calculate like this, not like counting `1 year`, but in month its equal `14 month`, and in day its `410 day`

Comment: Your query with the same data return this: `{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59fabb20d7905ef056f55ac1"),
    "years" : 1.0,
    "months" : 15.0,
    "days" : 492.0
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59fab630203f02f035301fc3"),
    "years" : 1.0,
    "months" : 17.0,
    "days" : 551.0
}`

Comment: @jones Gotha! Brain melt as I was not thinking about the "rollup" and just adjusting accordingly. Simply needs another `$project` stage for the final result.

Comment: @jones Yeah sorry, I was just stumbling over my modulo's for a moment. I think it looks right.

Comment: Sorry, but now it returns empty.

Comment: @jones Dude. What returns empty? There isn't even any data in your question. If you have "empty" then it's misnamed fields.

Comment: Once again sorry that take your time, i have missed a point in my question, and updated. Could you please check it.

Comment: @jones Your missed point makes your question pretty much an exact copy of another question, just renaming some fields. So right now I'm kind of inclined to flag both posts. Already answered the question you originally asked.

Comment: Which question? can i have a link to look at that?

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your code by using client side processing with [`moment js`](https://momentjs.com/docs/) library.

All the date time math is handled by moment js library. Use [`duration`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/durations/) to calculate the reduced time [`diff`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/)

Use reduce to add the time diff across all the array elements followed by moment duration to output the time in years/months/days.

It solves two issues :

1. Gives you accurate difference in years month and days between two dates.
2. Gives you expected format.

For example:

```
var education = [
   {
      "courseName": "Java",
      "from" : new Date("2010-12-08T00:00:00.000Z"),
      "to" : new Date("2011-05-31T00:00:00.000Z"), 
      "isGoingOn": false
   },
   {
      "courseName": "PHP",
      "from" : new Date("2013-12-08T00:00:00.000Z"),
      "to" : new Date("2015-05-31T00:00:00.000Z"), 
      "isGoingOn": false
   },
   {
      "courseName": "Mysql",
      "from" : new Date("2017-02-08T00:00:00.000Z"),
      "to" : null, 
      "isGoingOn": true
   }
];

var reducedDiff = education.reduce(function(prevVal, elem) {
    if(elem.isGoingOn) elem.to = new Date();
    var diffDuration = moment(elem.to).diff(moment(elem.from));
    return prevVal + diffDuration;
}, 0);

var duration = moment.duration(reducedDiff);

alert(duration.years() +" y, " + duration.months() + " m, " +  duration.days() + " d " );
var durationstr =  duration.years() +" y, " + duration.months() + " m, " +  duration.days() + " d ";
```

MongoDb integration:

```
var reducedDiff = db.getCollection('user').find({},{education:1}).reduce(function(...
```